# setInterval on child component method called with refs to child at parent component

Tags: vue.js

I want to execute setInterval in the child component from the parent component. When I do `console.log` in `start` it appears in the console, however the interval doesn't start. If I call the method in child component, then it works.

Child methods:

```
stop() {
     clearInterval(this.t);
        },
start() {
     this.timer = setInterval(() => {this.call()}, 1000);
}
```

Parent method:

```
methods: {
    update() {
       this.$refs.childComponent.start();
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use arrow function in setInterval, it won't clear. You can do like this
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hopper-igr2pv?file=/src/App.vue)